# Issues in Displaying Metabox in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the following code, everything saves properly but I cannot get it to display properly on the homepage of the website.

The problem is it *displays doubled* on the post page and *shows up in a random place* on the homepage. However I want it to only display on a certain place on the home page.

```
function home_page_position_get_meta( $value ) {
    global $post;

    $field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value, true );
    if ( ! empty( $field ) ) {
        return is_array( $field ) ? stripslashes_deep( $field ) : stripslashes( wp_kses_decode_entities( $field ) );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function home_page_position_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'home_page_position-home-page-position',
        __( 'Home Page Position', 'home_page_position' ),
        'home_page_position_home_page_position_html',
        'post',
        'side',
        'default'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'home_page_position_add_meta_box' );


function home_page_position_home_page_position_html( $post) {
    wp_nonce_field( '_home_page_position_home_page_position_nonce', 'home_page_position_home_page_position_nonce' ); 
    $home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position_value =  get_post_meta($post->ID,'home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position',true);
?>

    <p>
        <label for="home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position"><?php _e( 'Box Position', 'home_page_position' ); ?></label><br>
        <select name="home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position">

            <option id='none-none' value='none' name='none_' <?php selected($home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position_value, 'none'); ?> >None</option>
            <option id='box-01' value='box01' name='box_01' <?php selected($home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position_value, 'box01'); ?> >Box 01</option>
            <option id='box-02' value='box02' name='box_02' <?php selected($home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position_value, 'box02'); ?> >Box 02</option>
            <option id='box-03' value='box03' name='box_03' <?php selected($home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position_value, 'box03'); ?> >Box 03</option>

        </select>
    </p>    <p>

        <label for="home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title"><?php _e( 'Page Title', 'home_page_position' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title" id="home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title" value="<?php echo home_page_position_get_meta( 'home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title' ); ?>">
    </p>    <p>

        <label for="home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction"><?php _e( 'Introduction', 'home_page_position' ); ?></label><br>
        <textarea name="home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction" id="home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction" ><?php echo home_page_position_get_meta( 'home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction' ); ?></textarea>

    </p>    <p>

        <label for="home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page"><?php _e( 'Link To Page', 'home_page_position' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page" id="home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page" value="<?php echo home_page_position_get_meta( 'home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page' ); ?>">
    </p><?php
}


function home_page_position_home_page_position_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_nonce'], '_home_page_position_home_page_position_nonce' ) ) return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    if ( isset( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position', esc_attr( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position'] ) );

    if ( isset( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title', esc_attr( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title'] ) );

    if ( isset( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction', esc_attr( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction'] ) );

    if ( isset( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page', esc_attr( $_POST['home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'home_page_position_home_page_position_save' );


function cd_display_quote( $value )
{
     // We're in the loop, so we can grab the $post variable
    global $post;

    $position = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position', true );
    $pTitle = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title', true );
    $intro = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction', true );
    $link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page', true );  

    if( $position != 'none' ) {
        echo $position;
        echo $pTitle;
        echo $intro;
        echo $link;        
    }


    // Return the values: quote first, then the content
    return $value;
}
add_action('the_content', 'cd_display_quote');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

Your echoing data rather than returning it from the method meaning your metadata will always be output *before* the content is supposed to be output.

Instead, try the following code for outputting your content:

```
function cd_display_quote( $value )
{
     // We're in the loop, so we can grab the $post variable
    global $post;

    $position = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_box_position', true );
    $pTitle = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_page_title', true );
    $intro = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_introduction', true );
    $link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_page_position_home_page_position_link_to_page', true );  

    $prepend = '';
    if( $position != 'none' ) {
        $prepend .= $position;
        $prepend .= $pTitle;
        $prepend .= $intro;
        $prepend .= $link;        
    }


    // Return the values: quote first, then the content
    return prepend  . $value;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'cd_display_quote');
```

## Explanation:

You may notice that I've changed `add_action` to `add_filter` for `the_content` - this isn't *vital* but it's good practice. You see, WordPress actually runs the same code for `add_action` *and* `add_filter` - the only real difference is that 'actions' don't have to return a value, they're used as hooks to run some code or perform a task at a specific time. 'Filters' on the other hand, are exactly that - a value is passed to a callback method and a filtered value is expected to be returned.

This extract from this article (http://www.zell-weekeat.com/wordpress-actions-and-filters/) sums it up quite well:

**Actions**

- When something has to be **added**
- declared with add_action().
- used with do_action().

**Filters**

- When something has to be **changed**
- declared with apply_filters().
- used with add_filters().

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Still learning and trying to figure stuff out. very much apprecaited.